# Dynamically requiring files?

Tags: ruby, dynamic, rubygems, namespaces, require

Does anyone know enough about Ruby's `require` to tell me if the following is valid syntax:

```
class Something

  def initialize(mode)
     case mode
     when :one then require 'some_gem'
     when :two then require 'other_gem'
     end
  end

end

s = Something.new
```

If so, will the `require` place the gem into the global namespace as it would when at the top of the file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> If so, would the require place the gem
>   into the global namespace as the same
>   require at the top of the file would?

Yes. `require` doesn't have scope, while `load` does.

Comment: Fantastic, thats what i wanted to know :)

Answer (score 6):

**Yes it's perfectly valid and works as expected because require isn't scoped**

Require pulls in the code from the specified file and attempts to use it in-place - that might mean that it isn't sensible to do but yes it can be done.

The local method scope would be unaffected and any class definition etc would be at the expected scope

Comment: apologies about the spelling ;)

Comment: No problem - great question (+1 from me)